# Adding item to cart using REST API magento 2 shows price as zero

Tags: magento2

I can successfully add item to the cart using this rest API from my APP.

> POST /V1/carts/mine/items

However the item is added with a price of ZERO.

The new quote was created from the APP using this API.

> POST /V1/carts/mine

But when I try to add an item from magento web the price is showing correct value.

I am using magento 2 .

Comment: This was 5 months ago and was there any solution? Its disappointing that magento dev experts aren't addressing this issue

Answer (score 5):

```
Here is the solution of this issue

Open file 'vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php'.
Find function 'createEmptyCartForCustomer'.
Add below code inside try{}  (at start of try), before line number 234
$quote->getBillingAddress();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
After adding these 2 lines it will not show 0 price again.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution of this issue follow below steps**

> **step 1)** Go to file 'vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php'(override this
> file using preference dnt make chanage in core files)
>
> **step 2)** Edit this function 'createEmptyCartForCustomer'.
>
> **step 3)** In try before saving quote line number 234 add below code

```
$quote->getBillingAddress();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
```