# Magento 2 Add to cart api Item price set zero in Quote Item table

Tags: magento2, api

I am trying to add product to cart with Magento 2 default API.

```
POST : http://{{magento2}}/rest/V1/carts/mine/items

Request : {
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "p2",
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 100,
        "quote_id": 7227
    }   
}
```

but when i first time add product to cart using API than it set product price 0 in Quote Item table. After second time add product to cart using same API than it working fine.

I have try with Fresh Magento 2 but facing same issue.

Comment: You can try this way. It worked to me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137536/adding-item-to-cart-using-rest-api-magento-2-shows-price-as-zero

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below updated code :

you mention price with int format that's why it is not support try with float value.

```
POST : http://{{magento2}}/rest/V1/carts/mine/items

Request : {
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "p2",
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 100.00,
        "quote_id": 7227
    }   
}
```

**hope it works for you**